# CROSTON function for forecasting in R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, forecasting

I am not familiarized with the Croston function in R.
I have a time-serie and I would like to know which parameters in Croston function concern the amplitude and the frequency of my time-serie ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The information about the frequency is contained in the `ts` object that is passed to the `croston` function and not explicitly passed to the function. The documentation is fairly clear on this:

```
(From the help page of R)Usage:
croston(y, h = 10, alpha = 0.1, x = y)
```

Where `y` is the object of class `ts`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please precise what is the parameter "h" in croston function ? For example , if I have a time serie with frequency = 52 , and the length of my time serie is 152 , it means that I have  152/52= 2.9 periods , right ? So if h is the number of periods ( as I read ) , h = 2.9 in my case ?

Comment: You'r welcome.  `h` is the number of time steps ahead for which you need the forecasts. For ex. in your case with `h=10` will give you the forecasts for next 10 weeks.